# Two tables with same key in Rails instead of has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, primary-key

I am working on a Rail webapp. I have two models, User, which contains very basic information: id, username and password, and Profile, which includes profile for each user. (The main reason is to have a lightweight User model, which will be called regularly, and a full-fledged profile which will be called irregularly). Each of these models has many children.

Right now, I have Profile with its own primary key, then a foreign key user_id to match with User.

However, I wonder if I should have Profile model with the same key as User model (i.e., Profile.id == User.id if the records refer to the same user). This is convenience because when I have an object that belongs to User, I want it to belong to Profile and vise versa. For example, I can specify User has_many and Spec has_many relationship to ChildModel. Because they use the same key, I don't have to merge ChildModel to Spec, then Profile to User to find out user associated with child object.

The downside is in the future, if for some reason I have discrepancy between primary key of User and Spec, then I am in deep trouble.

What would be your recommendation for this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: In your question above are Profile and Spec actually the same model? Stated differently, do you have four models—Profile, User, Spec, and Child—or do you only have three models—Profile, User, and Child?

Comment: Yes. I corrected the example in my question. Further more, Profile and User have one-to-one relationship. I only split them into two models for light loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using a one-to-one relationship between `Profile` and `User`. You can create this using the `has_one` and `belongs_to` declarations.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

As stated in *Agile Web Development with Rails* Fourth Edition:

> There’s an important rule illustrated here: the model for the table that contains the foreign key *always* has the `belongs_to` declaration.

Comment: Rails convention is to use model name as singular form, while database table is plural

Comment: @MBO: You are correct. I was thinking of it backwards. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Matthew, this is what I am doing right now. However, the downside of this method is: when I have, say, Children that belongs to Profile and I need to find out user associated with a Child object, I need to merge with Profile first, before getting to User. It takes one extra merging step (which is costly b/c these two tables are big). I can't assign Children class to belong to User because of other constraints (such as form etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use has_one relation mapping like following

## user class

```
class User
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy # you probably want this on destroy
end
```

## migrations

```
create_table :users do |t|
   t.string :username
   t.string :password
end
create_table :profiles do |t|
   t. integer :user_id 
    ... other attributes
end
```